# ClearType in WPF when using AeroGlass

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, aero

I'm getting quite weird behavior with ClearType whenever I use AeroGlass in my WPF applications. I have found out that the following line sets my font rendering back to grey-scale:

```
mainWindowSrc.CompositionTarget.BackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
```

To get it back to work with AeroGlass I must set these .NET 4.0 properties to every control containing text:

`RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="ClearType"`

Then it looks like this:

[image: grey-scale on the left, cleartype on the right]

Is there a way to achive the same effect without setting these properties to every control on the window?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set this globally in the MainWindows constuctor.

Something like this:

```
RenderOptions.ClearTypeHintProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata { DefaultValue = ClearTypeHint.Enabled });
TextOptions.TextFormattingModeProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata { DefaultValue = TextFormattingMode.Display });
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! But can this code be moved somewhere else? I would like to keep it in my AeroGlass class.